# ssh: securing netconf only account

Tags: linux, ssh

I have to secure a Linux server that is managed by netconf over ssh. The netconf process is started by configured ssh subsystem and it works correctly. My question is about prohibiting netconf-only accounts from executing any other function from ssh command line: e.g  I would like 'ssh netconf_a@zzz.com ls' to fail.

My current plan is to use rbash as the shell and then tighten up the config. I am wondering are there easier solutions, e.g. can I set shell to be /usr/sbin/nologin or /usr/bin/true?

Answer (score 1):

In the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file you can set a certain private key to only run a certain command.

Answer (score 0):

I did some experiments and I found that the ssh subsystem is executed by 'sh -c ...' command. Apparently, there is no way to avoid having login shell.

And it seems that the only way out is to tighten up shell level restrictions.